# If $y_1$, $y_2$ are linearly independant solutions of a second order homogeneous ODE then $y_1^2(x) + y_2^2(x) \neq 0 \ \forall x$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let be an homogeneous second order linear ODE in an open interval $I$ :
$$y''(x) + p(x)y'(x) + q(x)y(x) = 0$$
$p, q : I \rightarrow \Bbb R$ continuous and let be $y_1, y_2 : I \rightarrow \Bbb R$ two linearly independant solutions of that ODE.

Then $y_1^2(x) + y_2^2(x) \neq 0 \ \forall x \in I.$

I think it has something to do with the Wronskian being different from zero but I can't find the link between both expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two functions $y_1$ and $y_2$ form a basis of the solution space ${\cal L}$. If $y_1^2(x_0)+y_2^2(x_0)=0$, hence $y_1(x_0)=y_2(x_0)=0$, you would not be able to satisfy the initial conditions $y(x_0)=1$, $y'(x_0)=0$, say.

Answer (score 1):

It is a consequence of the [Sturm separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm_separation_theorem): if $y_1(x_1)=0$ for some $x_1$, $y_2(x_1)$ cannot be $0$.

For learning differential equations, I advise you the marvelous "Differential equations" by King, Billingham, Otto (Cambridge U. P. 2003)

Comment: That is the theorem the exercise I'm doing right now want me to prove. But the first part of that exercise was to prove this statement.